# Custom Mesh Texture - Best Method?

Tags: particles, texture-painting

[image]

Hi, I’m wondering what method is best to achieve the darker lines texture on this hard working carrot. Texture paint, is what I’m assuming, but am not sure if there is a more efficient way like a hair particle system to sit on the surface.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want it to look actually bumpy or more stylized like you have it? The drawn lines look fine to me but I am assuming you want to take it a slightly different direction. Why not a procedural texture? John

Comment: Hi John, I’m new to blender. The drawn lines would be great, I’m not looking to apply normal map or anything. Could you help me out with the procedural texture process you’re referring to? Is that UV texture painting? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with texture paint, you would have control on how your spots appear exactly, or, as John says, you could do it procedurally.

If you choose this second option, here is a try. Set this nodes chain: *Texture Coordinate* (*Object* output) > *Mapping* node > *Texture* node (here *Musgrave*) > *ColorRamp* > *Mix Shader*. Mix your 2 colors (carrot color and spot color) in the *Mix Shader*. Play with the *Mapping* scale values to squish the spots on the right axis and with the parameters of the other nodes to give them the shape you want. At the end of the chain mix with a *Glossy*, and maybe also with a *Subsurface Scattering* to give it a bit of transparency.

[image]

Comment: Amazing thank you! This is really gonna help me, and help me learn how to do a lot more. Thank you for the detail and time you put into this!